# q-expansion principle for modular forms

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Let $f(z)$ be a modular form of some integral weight $k \geq 0$ and level $\Gamma_1(N)$ (I insist I want $\Gamma_1(N)$, not $\Gamma_0(N)$ or $\Gamma(N)$).
Thus for any $d \in (\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z)^\ast$ one has he diamond operator $\langle d \rangle$ which applied to $f$ gives rise to an other modular form $\langle d \rangle f$.

> Is it true that if the $q$-expansion of $f$ at infinity has its coefficients in $\mathbb Z[1/N]$, then the $q$-expansion of $\langle d \rangle f$ for $d \in (\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z)^\ast$ also have their $q$-expansion in $\mathbb Z[1/N]$?

I'd like an argument (or reference) or a counter-example. Thanks a lot (I am a little bit ashamed to ask this, but I am pretty confused right now).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes at least if $N>4$. Let $\Gamma=\Gamma_1(N)$ and for any ring $A$ let $\mathbf{M}_k(\Gamma;A)=\mathbf{M}_k(\Gamma;\mathbf{Z})\otimes_\mathbf{Z}A$, where $\mathbf{M}_k(\Gamma;\mathbf{Z})$ is the inverse image in $\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma)$ under the $q$-expansion map of $\mathbf{Z}[[q]]$. If $A$ is a subring of $\mathbf{C}$, then $\mathbf{M}_k(\Gamma;A)$ can be identified with the inverse image under the $q$-expansion map of $A[[q]]\subseteq\mathbf{C}[[q]]$. This follows from the $q$-expansion principle (see the discussion following Theorem 12.3.4 in Diamond and Im's article on modular forms and modular curves). We also have $\mathbf{M}_k(\Gamma;A)=\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma;A)$ for $A$ any flat $\mathbf{Z}$-algebra, where the target is the geometrically defined $A$-module of modular forms of level $\Gamma$ and weight $k$ (see Theorem 12.3.7 in *loc. cit.*).

The action of the diamond operators can be defined on $\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma;A)$ geometrically and when $A=\mathbf{C}$, we get the usual diamond operators via $\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma)\simeq\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma;\mathbf{C})$. This is enough to conclude that if $A$ is any subring of $\mathbf{C}$, $\mathbf{M}_k(\Gamma;A)$ is preserved by the diamond operators.

EDIT: To be slightly more detailed (I think this would be clearer if I could produce the commutative diagram I have in mind, but I can't), we have diamond operators on $\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma;A)$ and on $\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma;\mathbf{C})$. Since $\mathbf{M}_k(\Gamma;A)=\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma;A)$, we get diamond operators on the "naive" module $\mathbf{M}_k(\Gamma;A)$ of modular forms with coefficients in $A$. Under $\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma;\mathbf{C})=\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma)$ (the LHS is the geometrically defined space and the RHS is the analytically defined space), the geometrically defined diamond operators on the source correspond to the usual diamond operators on $\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma)$. Finally, the composite $\mathbf{M}_k(\Gamma;A)=\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma;A)\hookrightarrow\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma;\mathbf{C})=\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma)$ is the usual inclusion of the source into the target, and by construction, the diamond operators on $\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma)$ induce the ones on $\mathbf{M}_k(\Gamma;A)$. This shows that this $A$-submodule is stable under the diamond operators.

Comment: Wonderful! This was exactly the reference I was looking for. And moreover, that works even for $\mathbb Z[1/N]$ replaced simply by $\mathbb Z$, which is great. The restriction $N>4$ is not a big deal, though I'd like to know if it is really necessary.

Comment: What got me confused in the first place is the reading of an old paper by Naomi Jochnowitz, "Congruences Between Systems of Eigenvalues Of Modular Forms", Trans. AMS, vol. 270, 1982. There she defines (page 10=page278) $M$ as the set of modular forms $f$ of weight $k$ and level $N$ s.t. the $q$-expansion at infinity of $\langle d \rangle f$ has coefficients in $\bf Q$ and $l$-integral ($l$ is prime not dividing $N$) for all $d$. By what you say, it amounts to the same to just asks this for $f$ itself, instead of $\langle d \rangle f$ for all $d$.

Comment: Right! Yes, it works over $\mathbf{Z}$, and Diamond and Im say that it works over $\mathbf{Z}$ even when when $N\leq 4$ because in this case the diamond operators act by $\pm 1$. So I guess it works for any $\mathbf{Z}$-submodule of the space of modular forms in that case.